# Is there an as3 video player that runs in flash player 9.0.16.0?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flv, flvplayback

There is a known issue in Flash Player 9.0.16.0. It has to do with the FullscreenEvent. I guess because of that the FLVPlayback component doesn't work with this version of the player.

I don't want to reinvent the wheel and build another FLV Player using the Video class.

Does anyone know about a FLV Player that runs in Flash Player 9.0.16.0 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Jeroen or JW Player used to work on Flash 8. Here is the site for 
the most recent incarnations:

http://www.longtailvideo.com/

The player for earlier versions were open source and are what most video players were built on.

**ALSO**, given the flash player penetration for version 10 and 9, I wouldn't worry about any issues occuring with that early version of Flash 9.

Comment: Thanks Dru. I've tried the JW player. The current version is made in as3. The player detects if it's run under Flash Player 9.0.16.0 and removes the fullscreen button. I wonder if I have an as2 FLV player with full screen loaded in an as3 movie and use Local Connection to call functions back and forth, will fullscreen still work under this nasty player version ?

Comment: BTW, why are you concerned with this version. The number of installs for it is so low it isn't worth supporting?

Comment: I wish I didn't have to worry about this version. It so happens the client has this version and it would take ages to update all the machines. Just that kind of luck.

Comment: If the client goes to youtube.com, hulu, facebook.com, or myspace... do they get asked to upgrade?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Dru. On youtube there is a warning and the user is asked to upgrade. Video plays and fullscreen button is available, but it doesn't work properly.